# How to remove unnecessary files from ExtJs 4.1 in Maven project?

Tags: maven, extjs, extjs4, reduction

I'm working on existing (not mine) Maven project which generates pretty big .war file ~37MB. More than 20MB is made of ExtJs 4.1 files (.js and .css).

I'm not sure which files are really required and which can be removed. I found out that I can remove unnecessary files with Sencha CMD but I'm not sure if it is compatibile with ExtJs 4.1. However, I tried to run it, but it always says *Command must be run from an app or package folder.*

Here is structure of my project: http://prntscr.com/4o97zy

Any help is apperciated!

Comment: You do not know in advance that you will need, use maven minify plugin http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks Igor, I reduced css this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production you can just ext-all.* and remove rest of them which reduces size application size by 10MB. Here is the bare minimum structure that you can have in production. If you use any additional plugins include them as well. I would suggest to keep ext-all-debug.js/css as well, use maven profiles to take care of copying ext-all.* or ext-all-debug*.

[image]

The above structure is of size 2.5MB, more or less that will almost be sufficient. You can miniify these files and put it into your war. There are multiple ways of doing it. You can use ycompressor to compress and put it in your webapp or from server side you can compress files whenever user requests(Google-web utilities).